# How to Calculate total area of pixels in each class in multi class segmented image

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I have a multi class segmented image consisting of labels of 4 different classes represented in 4 different colors ( Darkblue,red,yellow and sky blue ), i would like to calculate the total area of pixels in each class label of segmented prediction.

I tried writing this code for obtaining total number of pixels in each label but i am not able to get any result which consists of total number of pixels in each corresponding class label.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from skimage import data, io, img_as_ubyte
from skimage.filters import threshold_multiotsu

# Read an image
image = io.imread("images/Ulcer_segmented.jpg")


# Apply multi-Otsu threshold 
thresholds = threshold_multiotsu(image, classes=5)

# Digitize (segment) original image into multiple classes.
#np.digitize assign values 0, 1, 2, 3, ... to pixels in each class.
regions = np.digitize(image, bins=thresholds)
output = img_as_ubyte(regions)  #Convert 64 bit integer values to uint8

plt.imsave("images/Ulcer_segmented..jpg", output)


props = measure.regionprops_table(label_image, output, 
                          properties=['label',
                                      'area', 'equivalent_diameter',
                                      'mean_intensity', 'solidity'])
```

[image: multi class segmented image]

Comment: if you have class map then you can count number of instances in the map with `np.count_nonzero`

Comment: @DominikFicek, Thanks, for your suggestion, i tried it but i am not able to get any result concerning area of pixels, also I would like to plot each label separately . can you provide me an example

Comment: I can't be specific because your question is too broad. Provide some code and describe what your data looks like and then I can provide some specific examples

Comment: @DominikFicek , I have provided the code , could you please review it

Comment: what you probably want to do is compute the image's histogram but it's hard for me to add a specific code as I'm not sure what your input image is exactly, is it in RGB format, is it a single channel class map, or any other format?

Comment: @DominikFicek , My input image is in RBG format , it has 4 classes , i want to find number of pixels in each of the class

Answer (score 0):

This is described in the [docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_label.html):

```py
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops

# Read an image
image = io.imread("your/image.jpg")

# label image regions
label_image = label(image)

for region in regionprops(label_image):
    print(region.area)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that, it gives an array with numbers like [6 3 5... etc], i need total number of pixels for each corresponding class indicated by different color

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to get an image histogram the issue of using `np.histogram` or `skimage.exposure.histogram` is that your image is not single-channel and using these functions you would get a histogram of flattened image which would not yield the expected results.

The way you chose to overcome this problem is using otsu thresholding which I'm not sure if works as the documentation states that it expects a single channel (grayscale) image.

The knowledge of the colors used to represent your classes would help here, you could do something like

```py
coors = [
    [cls_0_rgb_color],
    [cls_1_rgb_color],
    [cls_2_rgb_color],
    [cls_3_rgb_color]
]
areas = [np.count_nonzero(np.all(img == c, axis=-1)) for c in colors]
```

If you don't know exactly what colors the classes have you probably have to reduce the last dimension of your image to uniquely represent the 3-dimensional color (I'm not sure exactly how this is done correctly, maybe someone smarter than me can answer this in a new question). What I would do is convert the image to HSV format and use the hue component as a class representation.

```py
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv
hsv = rgb2hsv(image)
hue = hsv[:, :, 0]
areas, bin_edges = np.histogram(hue, bins=4)
```

What could be tricky here is deciphering which area corresponds to what class but knowing approximately what colors to expect and from [knowing how colors in hue space are aligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#/media/File:Hsl-hsv_models.svg) we could say that the order would be `red, yellow, light_blue, dark_blue` or `yellow, light_blue, dark_blue, red` as red hue is symmetrical around 0 or 360 degrees. Checking the bin_edges vector could do the trick here.

```py
# set red_threshold experimentally
if bin_edges[1] < red_threshold:
    # (red, yellow, light_blue, dark_blue)
else:
    # (yellow, light_blue, dark_blue, red)
```